# Actualizar estado de pedido cuando pasa la fecha de entrega del pedido SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

He estado investigando la manera de crear un trigger en sql para que cuando la fecha de entrega del pedido llegue, automáticamente se actualiza el campo de estado de pedido, de en proceso a entregado.

Mis pruebas no han funcionado aun, tenéis alguna idea de como se puede hacer

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves por favor y a partir de eso podemos ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Y la estructura de base de datos nos vendría genial para comprobar el resultado que te propongamos: phpMyAdmin, Exportar